# React/Redux - Can't send a store value into props of a component (mapStateToProps)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a Twitter-like app with React & Redux,

I have a rootReducer that contains two reducers (user and newTweet), and I want to send the isConnected state value from user reducer to a component called "Accueil".

Here's the component that needs to get the isConnected value from the store state :

```
function Accueil({ isConnected }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("is connected ", isConnected); <---- ALWAYS UNDEFINED
  }, [isConnected]);

  return (
    <div className="Accueil">
      {isConnected ? (
        <div class="container">
          <Nav />
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col m12 l3">
              <AccountNav />
            </div>
            <div class="col m12 l6">
              <Feed />
            </div>
            <div class="col m12 l3">
              <Searchbar />
              <TrendingTopic />
              <Infos />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <NotConnected />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  counter: state.user.isConnected,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Accueil);
```

Here's the rootReducer combining the 2 reducers :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import user from "./user";
import newTweet from "./newTweet";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user,
  newTweet,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Here's the user reducer code :

```
import { LOGIN, LOGOUT } from "../constants/types";

const initialState = {
  isConnected: false,
  user: {},
};

export default function user(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN:
      return { ...state, isConnected: true };
    case LOGOUT:
      return { ...state, isConnected: false, user: {} };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Does someone has an idea ? Thank you

Comment: because the mapStateToProps has to be done in a container and not in a "dumb" component no ?

Comment: why ? You can do this also directly in the functional component. This is actually one of the best advantage of redux : you are not bound to the constraints of passing props from parent to child. Let us know if this resolve your problem

Comment: ok I did this but it's still undefined, i'm updating the question code

Comment: how do you create your store ? can you show your createstore init ? also what do you get if you print just props in Acceuil ?

Comment: In the last example you post : the props is "counter" change it also to isConnected

Comment: maybe can I send you the github repo : https://github.com/Versifiction/twister

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218144/discussion-between-yossefaz-and-versifiction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not connecting your component to the redux store and your props should be `isConnected` not `counter`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

function Accueil({ isConnected }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("is connected ", isConnected)
  }, [isConnected]);

  return (
    <div className="Accueil">
      {isConnected ? (
        <div class="container">
          <Nav />
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col m12 l3">
              <AccountNav />
            </div>
            <div class="col m12 l6">
              <Feed />
            </div>
            <div class="col m12 l3">
              <Searchbar />
              <TrendingTopic />
              <Infos />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <NotConnected />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isConnected: state.user.isConnected,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Accueil);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `Accueil` component, the name of the prop is `isConnected`. If you want to map a value in the redux state to that prop, you should use the same name in `mapStateToProps`.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isConnected: state.user.isConnected,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Accueil);
```